# How can I take last N items from a list in F#?

Tags: f#

I would do something like

```
let last n xs = xs |> List.rev |> Seq.take n |> List.ofSeq |> List.rev
```

I am not sure about turning a list to a sequence and back though. Is this how you do it F#?

Comment: You could just write your own take for lists. `let rec take n ls =
    match ls, n with
    | _ , 0 -> []
    | x :: rs, _ -> x :: take (n-1) rs
    | _ -> []`

Answer (score 5):

### Seq + Skip

Taking the last N items is equivalent to skipping the first (length - N) items, so for a Sequence as input (and output), you could do something like:

```
let last n xs = Seq.skip ((Seq.length xs) - n) xs
```

(or, with piping, `let last n xs = xs |> Seq.skip (Seq.length xs - n)`

and for a List as input (and output) you could do:

```
let last n xs = List.toSeq xs |> Seq.skip (xs.Length - n) |> Seq.toList
```

or by defining both, just pipe it to the sequence one:

```
let lastList n xs = List.toSeq xs |> last n |> Seq.toList
```

### Tail + Recursion

Alternatively, this can be achieved by (tail) recursively applying Tail as so:

```
let rec last n xs =
  if List.length xs <= n then xs
  else last n xs.Tail
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `List.foldBack` to traverse the list from the end:

```
let takeLast n list = 
    let (_, r) = List.foldBack (fun e (i, acc) -> (i - 1, if i <= 0 then acc else e :: acc)) list (n, [])
    r
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid rebuilding the list, you may use a simple recursive algorithm.

Note, we are not using neither `List.Cons` nor `Seq.toList` which does the same internally.

```
let lastN n xs =
    let rec skip n xs = 
        match n, xs with
        | _, []     -> []   // empty list, returning unchanged
        | 0, _      -> xs   // found an element at which the remainder
                            // of the list is to be returned
        | n', h::t  -> skip (n-1) t    // proceed to next iteration

    let toSkip = (List.length xs) - n  // how many elements to skip
    if toSkip < 0 then xs   // or an exception, depending on expected behavior
    elif toSkip = 0 then xs // requested exactly as many elements
                            // as the list contains
    else skip toSkip xs

// usage
let data = [1 .. 10000000]
let stopWatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
stopWatch.Start()
data
|> lastN 3
|> List.iter (printf "%d ")
stopWatch.Stop()
printfn "\nelapsed: %f ms" stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds
```

Output:

```
9999998 9999999 10000000
elapsed: 194.846700 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Variation on chamila_c's function:-

```
/// Returns the last abs(n) items in the specified sequence.
let lastN n xs =
    // The number to skip will be negative if n is too large; this will result in 0 items being skipped.
    // By taking abs(n), the number to skip can't get too large, and we avoid an exception being thrown.
    xs |> Seq.skip (Seq.length xs - abs n)
```